# Not able to parse String to Java Date

Tags: java, datetime

I have a string `"2017-01-03T02:20:52+00:00"` I want to convert into a `LocalDateTime`.

I tried the code below

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String date = "2009-07-16T19:20:30-05:00";
        String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
        DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, inputFormatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
     }
}
```

I tried various pattern but every time I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2009-07-16T19:20:30-05:00' could not be parsed at index 19
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:11)
```

Comment: At index 19 in your date String, there is a "-", which may not fit to the pattern used…

Comment: Please see the Java DateFormat doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html. The symbol 'Z' is the RFC 822 time zone, for example: -0800. So if you remove the semicolon from your input, it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, @Korashen is right. Otherwise, you could use X instead of Z in your pattern to use the ISO 8601 format.

Comment: @Korashen What semicolon in the input?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Well, your point is valid. I refere to the last one, being part of the timezone. So change "-05:00" to "-0500" to match the format requirements.

Comment: @Korashen Thats a colon (:), not a semicolon (;). Hence my confusion.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Oh, I'm sorry, got that mixed up (non-native english)

Comment: You could also do `OffsetDateTime.parse("2009-07-16T19:20:30-05:00").toLocalDateTime()`. Or use the built-in formatter `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single `Z` does not allow `:` in the timezone. Use `ZZZZZ` (five Z) for the extended format.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your `date` String is incorrect

Change it like so:

```
String date = "2009-07-16T19:20:30-0500";
```

Note the change before the `timezone`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your date format, you can use this pattern:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String date = "2009-07-16T19:20:30-0500";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
```

or

```
String date = "2009-07-16T19:20:30-05:00";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz";
```